# Combining 2 images in javascript

Tags: javascript

So I know this question has been asked before; however, for some reason I cannot get the height and width of my canvas to display correctly.

Here is what I currently have, but for some reason the image gets cut off and does not display the entire image. Any thoughts? Thanks!

```
function mergeImages(source1, source2){
    let image1 = new Image();
    image1.src = source1;
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    image1.onload = function (){
         c.width = image1.width;
        ctx.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, image1.width, image1.height);

        let image2 = new Image();
        image2.src = source2;
        image2.onload = function (){
            ctx.drawImage(image2, 0, image1.height, image2.width, image2.height);
            console.log(c.toDataURL("image/png"));
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Your ctx height should probably be image1.height + image2.height (and same for width). You're setting the width to just the width of the first image.

Answer (score 0):

You are making the assumption that image1 is loaded before image2, this might be 99% true.

I suggest you get the images first and then write it to the canvas. In your current code you are setting the width and not the height

Attaching two solutions

This is based on what you have, with just some changes around canvas width and height

```
function mergeImages(source1, source2){
    let image1 = new Image();
    image1.src = source1;
    var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    image1.onload = function (){


        let image2 = new Image();
        image2.src = source2;
        image2.onload = function (){
            c.width = Math.max(image1.width, image2.width)
            c.height = image1.height + image2.height
            ctx.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, image1.width, image1.height);
            ctx.drawImage(image2, 0, image1.height, image2.width, image2.height);
            console.log(c.toDataURL("image/png"));
        };
    };
}
mergeImages('https://i.imgur.com/5HtV0Nv.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/5HtV0Nv.jpg')
```

This is based on promises

```
function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener('load', () => {
      resolve(image);
    });
    img.src = url;
  });
}
async function asyncMergeImages(source1, source2){
    let c = document.getElementById('canvas');
    let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    let image1 = await loadImage(source1)
    let image2 = await loadImage(source2)
    c.width = Math.max(image1.width, image2.width)
    c.height = image1.height + image2.height
    ctx.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, image1.width, image1.height);
    ctx.drawImage(image2, 0, image1.height, image2.width, image2.height);
    console.log("async",c.toDataURL("image/png"));
}


asyncMergeImages('https://i.imgur.com/csFntM8.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/5HtV0Nv.jpg')
```